# Извлечение домена из ссылки и поиск ссылок по имени домена

Tags: python, парсер, url, urllib

Задача стоит такая:

1. Сверка ссылок по домену(*) из TXT №2 с TXT №1
2. Сохранение уникальны ссылок в отдельный TXT №3
3. Добавление уникальных ссылок в TXT №1

При сверке по  доменам - идет сверка только доменов сайта без: http:// и без https:// , так же при сверке по домену не учитывается все что после доменной зоны (.com , .ru , и т.п.)

Я разделил программу на подзадачи и написал код на python 3.8:
Подзадачи:

Исходные данные:

```
1.txt

http://site.com/
https://sit1e.com/vwdsvdfw/vwdefei/userpanel?cid=2
https://site.com/index.php?id=1
http://sit2e.com/
http://site.com/vwifow/fwviiwf?

2.txt

http://site.com/
https://sit1e213.com/vwdsvdfw/vwdefei/userpanel?cid=2
https://site.com/index.php?id=1
http://sit222e.com/
http://site.com/vwifow/fwviiwf?
```

1) Достать домены:

```
import re

f1 = open('1.txt')
f2 = open('2.txt')

filevar1 = f1.read()
filevar2 = f2.read()

domains1 = re.findall(r'\/\/([\w\-]+)', filevar1) 
domains2 = re.findall(r'\/\/([\w\-]+)', filevar2)

#Вывод доменов с новой строки 

with open('domains1.txt','w') as out:
    for domen in domains1:
        print(domen,file=out)
with open('domains2.txt','w') as out:
    for domen in domains2:
        print(domen,file=out)

f1.close()
f2.close()

input('Нажмите Enter, чтобы выйти из программы')
```

Результат работы участка кода:

```
domains1.txt

site
sit1e
site
sit2e
site

domains2.txt

site
sit1e213
site
sit222e
site
```

2) Сравнить домены:

```
import re

def diff():
    with open('result1.txt') as text_one, \
            open('result2.txt') as text_two:
        return set(text_one) ^ set(text_two)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open('output.txt', 'w') as result:
        for i in diff():
            result.write(i)

input('Нажмите Enter, чтобы выйти')
```

Выходные данные:

```
output.txt

sit1e
sit2e
sit1e213
sit222e
```

3) Найти исходные строки по выделенным доменам в исходных файлах и записать их в отдельный файл.
с этим возникают проблемы. Не знаю какую регулярную функцию использовать.

PS: пока искал ответ на свой вопрос, то заметил, что моя программа не учитывает субдомены, вроде для этого уже существует специальная функция в python: urlparse, но я не могу понять как ее использовать.

Можно ли как-то сократить код программы, чтобы не писать 3-й блок программы?
Можно-ли реализовать эту задачу проще?

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе небольшой пример входных данных (в таком виде чтобы текст можно было скопировать - __не скриншотом__) и то что вы хотите получить на выходе

Comment: Stuckoverflow не позволяет мне добавлять много ссылок, потому что у меня недостаточный рейтинг, я добавлю ссылку на sendspace, где будет файл txt

Comment: примеры лучше всего привести прямо в теле вопроса, отформатировав текст как код. Кроме того ваши примеры входных данных не очень воспроизводимые - 1) вы привели данные состоящие только из ссылок (нет необходимости использовать `re.findall()` для таких данных); 2) сравнение в ваших примерах идет по всему URL, а не так как описано  в вопросе. Советую оформить воспрос в соответствии с: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Дополнил и учел ошибки в программе и дополнил вопрос входными и выходными данными, чтобы лучше читалось.

Comment: по поводу пункта 3) - поиск будет производиться по тем же исходным файлам - `1.txt`, `2.txt`?

Comment: Да, по тем же файлам

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для чтения доменов из файлов со ссылками можно использовать следующую функцию:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse

def get_domains(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        return ['.'.join(urlparse(line.strip()).netloc.split('.')[:-1])
                for line in f]
```

Проверка:

```
dom1 = get_domains(r'C:\temp\1.txt')
dom2 = get_domains(r'C:\temp\2.txt')

print(dom1)
# ['site', 'sit1e', 'site', 'sit2e', 'site']
print(dom2)
# ['site', 'sit1e213', 'site', 'sit222e', 'site']
```

Работа со списками доменов как со множествами - объединение, пересечение, симметрическая разность:

```
In [31]: set(dom1) | set(dom2)
Out[31]: {'sit1e', 'sit1e213', 'sit222e', 'sit2e', 'site'}

In [32]: set(dom1) & set(dom2)
Out[32]: {'site'}

In [33]: set(dom1) ^ set(dom2)
Out[33]: {'sit1e', 'sit1e213', 'sit222e', 'sit2e'}
```

Поиск ссылок по списку доменов:

```
import re

def search_domains(filename, doms):
    with open(filename) as f:
        text = f.read()
    pat = r'(https?://[^./\r\n]*?\b(?:{})\b[^\r\n]*)'.format('|'.join(doms))
    return re.findall(pat, text)
```

Проверка:

```
In [47]: doms = set(dom1) ^ set(dom2)

In [48]: doms
Out[48]: {'sit1e', 'sit1e213', 'sit222e', 'sit2e'}

In [49]: search_domains(r'C:\temp\1.txt', doms)
Out[49]: ['https://sit1e.com/vwdsvdfw/vwdefei/userpanel?cid=2', 'http://sit2e.com/']

In [50]: search_domains(r'C:\temp\2.txt', doms)
Out[50]:
['https://sit1e213.com/vwdsvdfw/vwdefei/userpanel?cid=2',
 'http://sit222e.com/']
```

PS с записью результатов в файл я думаю вы справитесь сами.

Comment: Да, справлюсь, спасибо

Comment: В проверке заметил, что функция поиска ссылок по домену не находит уникальные, а выводит все, кроме уникальных. Почему так и как это исправить?

Comment: @Ian, исправил ответ - проверьте пожалуйста

Comment: теперь все работает корректно, спасибо за помощь! :)